# Gradle (Maven) : Why is it recommended to separate test-source and test-resources?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I mean, it is common in Java to load test resources over the `getResourceAsStream` method, for e.g.:

```
com.myapp.MyTestClass.class.getResourceAsStream("test.data")
```

and the separation of folders to sources and resources make extra complexity to create the same folder structure in resources, for e.g. `~/com/myapp/`

However, why is the default project structure of Gradle (or Maven) recommend to separate test-source and test-resources?

Comment: Because source is needed at compile time, resources are needed at runtime.  They're fundamentally different types of thing, so it makes sense (conventionally) to separate them.

Comment: How does the separation add complexity? Both of these folders are combined in the classpath when the tests are run. What easier method would you suggest for accesing the resources?

Comment: The complexity is to create second folders with same structure. My suggestion is to put test-data and test-sources together. Besides test-sources are not needed at runtime.